# Strange interface/TContext error when testing generic interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, generics, repository-pattern

I am getting a strange error "cannot convert from IStudentContext to TestStudentContext" when attempting to unit test a generic repository is C#. It seems I need to reimplement .Set() in my interface, is that right? Some code omitted for brevity but here is the basic setup. Forgive the large block of code I will add some additional context at the bottom!

`IStudentContext.cs`

```
public interface IStudentContext : IDisposable
{
    Database Database { get; }

    // Irrelevant tables omitted
    DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

`StudentContext.cs`

```
public class StudentContext : DbContext, IStudentContext
{
    public StudentContext() : base("name=StudentContext") {}

    // Irrelevant tables omitted
    public virtual DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

`TestStudentContext.cs`

```
public class TestStudentContext : DbContext, IStudentContext
{
    public TestStudentContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection: true) {}

    // Irrelevant tables omitted
    public virtual DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

`EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository.cs`

```
public class EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<TContext> : IGenericReadOnlyRepository where TContext : DbContext, IStudentContext
{
    protected readonly TContext Context;

    public EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository(TContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    // Irrelevant generic repo methods omitted
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string include = null, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
    {
        return GetQueryable(filter, orderBy, include, skip, take).ToList();
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string include = null, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
    {
        include = include ?? string.Empty;
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        query = include.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(query, (current, property) => current.Include(property));

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        if (skip.HasValue)
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);

        if (take.HasValue)
            query = query.Take(take.Value);

        return query;
    }
}
```

`StudentRepositoryTests.cs`

```
public class StudentRepositoryTests
{
    private IStudentContext Context { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Context = new TestStudentContext(Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetClasses_OrdersCorrectly()
    {
        // Calls to Context.Classes.Add() to set up DB omitted

        Context.SaveChanges();

        var repository = new EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<TestStudentContext>(Context);

        var results = repository.Get<Classes>().ToArray();

        // Assertions omitted
    }
}
```

As written, I get an error on `Context` in the `var repository` line of my test class. The error states `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IStudentContext' to 'TestStudentContext'`. If I change that line to `var repository = new EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<IStudentContext>(Context);`, then I get an error `The type 'IStudentContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IStudentContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.`

It looks like if I implement DbSet for all my database tables in `IStudentContext` that *might* fix the issue, but that feels like I'm reimplementing a lot of code just to be able to test something, so I would think there would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: @Igor I'm not married to this implementation - what is your suggestion for a better implementation? We are writing a public-facing API and my initial thought was the EF entities, a repository above that, and a business service above that (transforming the repository responses into the data structure that will be returned to the user).

Comment: I would recommend consuming the DbContext directly in the business services.

Comment: What are `TestPersonnelContext` and `IPersonnelContext`? It looks like you can just change the type of the `Context` property in your tests to `TestStudentContext` so `var repository = new EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<TestStudentContext>(Context);` will type check?

Comment: @Lee Just typos, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
var repository = new EntityFrameworkReadOnlyRepository<TestStudentContext>(Context);
```

`Context` is of type `IStudentContext`. Therefore you cannot pass that value to the ctor which expects `TestStudentContext`.

A simple fix is to make `private IStudentContext Context { get; set; }` of type `TestStudentContext`. Or, if you want to keep it `IStudentContext` then cast, or find another way to pass that value along without upcasting to `IStudentContext` first losing type information in the process.

> It seems I need to reimplement .Set() in my interface, is that right?

That should not be necessary. The compiler message points to the issue that I addressed.

---

In your repo you have chosen to make the caller specify where, order by etc. This is not a useful approach as it seems to me. It seems better to just have a `QueryTable<T>()` method and make the caller construct the query. You could make a helper function to build a query like that (I think that would be useless) but it's not necessary to make the repository responsible for build LINQ queries.

I also notices at a cursory look that the `TContext` parameter seems not necessary. You could use `DbContext` directly and simplify.